# Electric field of a finite line uniformly charged

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

A charge $Q$ is uniformly distributed along the $z$ axis.

[image]

Why because of the symmetry of the configuration is the electric field zero at z=0?

I understand the electric field cancellation in a spherical surface because of the symmetry of the configuration. But in this case, I don't see it that clear.

In what direction would point the electric field created at the origin by the chunk from 0 to L/2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is that electric fields add linearly.

Think of the charge as two identical chunks on either side of the origin, each having magnitude $\frac{Q}{2}$. Then each chunk contributes some electric field at the origin, of the same magnitude and opposite direction (think about the symmetry at play here). These two field components add up and cancel out, leaving you with zero electric field at the origin.

Comment: Could you tell me in what direction would point the electric field created at the origin by the chunk from 0 to L/2 ?

Comment: It would point in the $-z$ direction. You can show this via Coulomb's law, or conceptually. Every point along this chunk, treated like a point charge, will create a bit of field in the $-z$ direction by the definition of electric field. So they will add up for a total field in the $-z$ direction.

Comment: Another way to think of what direction the electric field points is this: for a given point in space, what will happen if we drop a small positive test charge there? Which way will it accelerate? Since like charges repel, it will feel a force in the $-z$ direction, and so that is the way the field points.

Comment: so the chunk from -L/2 to 0 will create an electric filed in the z direction a the origin?

Comment: Yes, that is the component that it contributes. And these two 'chunks' will create their fields of equal magnitude but opposite direction, and therefore will cancel out to reveal 0 total electric field at the origin.